# Find Total Sum of a column as All at the end of mysql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create a table like result with mysql so that i can use the data to plot in fusion charts so that i have totals in the y-axis and client_types in the x-axis, thus something like this

```
n+1'                     ' 
   '  '                  '
10 '  '   '          '   ' 
   '  '   '   '      '   '
0  '  '   '   '  '   '   '
   '__'___'___'__'___'___'___
      A   B   C  D  E   All
```

My Query as shown below returns

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT('client_type')) AS Total, client_type FROM `clients` GROUP BY client_type
```

returns

```
Total Client_type
 18     A
 26     B
 16     C
101     D
  2     E
```

SO what I want is to be able to add under client type 'All' and sum(Total) thus

```
Total Client_type
 18     A
 26     B
 16     C
101     D
  2     E
168     All
```

Suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You want `rollup`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, coalesce(client_type, 'All')
FROM `clients`
GROUP BY client_type with Rollup;
```

Note:  the expression `DISTINCT(COUNT('client_type'))` is close to non-sensical.  You basically never need `select distinct` with a `group by`.  The `distinct` applies to all the values in the `select`, so the parens around `count('client_type')` don't do anything.  And, you are counting a constant, the string `'client_type'`, when perhaps you intend the column.